# Tidy poorly formated data from Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In a SQL Server database, I have a table `T` where data is stored in an unfavourable (untidy) format. For each timestamp in `ColTimestamp`, it contains several variables in ColVar and corresponding values in ColVal, like that:

Table T

```
+---------+--------+--------------+
| ColVar  | ColVal | ColTimestamp |
+---------+--------+--------------+
| 'var01' | val101 |     ts1      |
| 'var02' | val102 |     ts1      |
            ...

| 'var50' | val150 |     ts1      |
| 'var01' | val201 |     ts2      |
| 'var02' | val202 |     ts2      |
            ...

| 'var50' | val250 |     ts2      |
| 'var01' | val301 |     ts3      |

          and so on...
```

I would like to extract data for a certain timestamp and convert it into a tidy format. For example, for ColTimestamp = ts1 I expect something like

```
+--------+--------+-                    -+--------+
| var01  | var02  |                      | var50  |
+--------+--------+- ... and son on ... -+--------+
| val101 | val102 |                      | val150 |
+--------+--------+-                    -+--------+
```

I already considered the following approach

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetTidy (@myTimestamp DATETIME)
RETURNS @TidyValuesAtTimestamp TABLE
(  
    var01 int NOT NULL,  
    var02 int NOT NULL, 
         ...
    var50 int NOT NULL 
)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @UntidyValuesTimestamp TABLE (ColVar VARCHAR, ColVal INT)

    INSERT INTO @UntidyValuesAtTimestamp
        SELECT * 
        FROM 'T' 
        WHERE 'ColTimestamp'= @myTimestamp;

    do something to fill @TidyValuesAtTimestamp with data from @UntidyValuesTimestamp and return it
END
GO
```

and then call it with

```
SELECT * FROM GetTidy (ts1);
```

I have some experience with other relational databases, but I've never worked with SQL Server. So my approach is based on what I think could work, and some research I did. For any high-level language, this would be easy, but for a couple of reasons I don't want to involve another technology.

Is there a way to achieve this only with a SQL Server expression or function? Easily readable and maintainable code is more important than run-time performance.

If needed, I can supply more information about the exact configuration of my SQL Server.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Columns are NOT fixed you're stuck with `Dynamic SQL` which is NOT allowed within a `Table-Valued Function`.

If the Columns are fixed, consider the following:

**Example**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTidy](@myTimestamp DATETIME)
Returns Table 
As
Return ( 
    Select *
     From (
            Select ColVar
                  ,ColVal 
             From  YourTable
             Where ColTimeStamp=@myTimestamp
          ) A
     Pivot (max([ColVal]) For [ColVar] in ([var01],[var02],[var50]) ) p
)
```

**Note:** This assumes you are looking for a single row per the timestamp parameter

Comment: _"If the Columns are fixed"_: Do you mean that I have a fixed set of `var01, var02, ..., var50`? I do, which is good, I assume.

I do look for a single row per timestamp.

Comment: @user3419513 Yes, I mean a fixed/constant  set columns var01 .. var50.   Variable columns means one ts would have 7 columns while another may have 25.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.